# MVC Route with Optional Section

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I would like to create a route for my MVC page that looks like this:

/Articles/
/Articles/Page/2
/Articles/Page/3

I want the default page to be 1, but if the page is 1, then don't actually show the /Page/ piece.

I started out with:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Articles",
    "Articles/Page/{page}",
            new { controller = "Articles", action = "Index", page = 1 }
);
```

The problem with this is that when I do:

```
 <%= Html.RouteLink("Articles", new { page = 1 }) %>
```

My route ends up being: /Articles/Page/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need two route definitions for this (untested):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "ArticlesDefault",
    "Articles",
    new { controller = "Articles", action = "Index", page = 1 }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Articles",
    "Articles/Page/{page}",
    new { controller = "Articles", action = "Index" }
);
```

and your controller action:

```
public ActionResult Index(int page)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: There is no reason to force the controller to supply the default value here.

Answer (score 1):

Put both in:

```
// This will match routes where the page equals one. Since the page can't
// be specifed here, it will drop to the next one for page values other
// than 1.
routes.MapRoute("Articles",
                "Articles",
                new { controller = "Articles", action = "Index", page = 1 } 
); 

// This route handles pages other than 1
routes.MapRoute(null,
                "Articles/Page/{page}",
                new { controller = "Articles", action = "Index" }
);
```

You don't need to do anything with the controller.